# Plots in a loop are overwritten

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, figure

I am trying to create several plots in a loop. The plots I create gets saved automatically in a different folder each time. This is the code

```
x = [2,4,6]
y = [1,2,3]
for i in x:
    for j in y:
        outputpath = './home/' + 'folder'+ str(i) + str(j)
        if not path.exists(outputpath):
            try:
                os.makedirs(outputpath)
            except OSError:
                print("Creation failed")
            else:
                print("Successfully created")
        a =  np.random.rand(1000)
        b = np.random.rand(20000)
        
        #Plotting a
        plt.scatter((range(0,len(a))),a)
        path1 = outputpath + '/' + 'a' + '.png'
        plt.savefig(path1)

        #Plotting b
        plt.scatter((range(0,len(b))),b)
        path2 = outputpath + '/' + 'b' + '.png'
        plt.savefig(path2)
```

The plots get saved in the appropriate folders. But every new plot that is generated is overwritten on the old plot. As shown in the figure below. This figure was created for i = 2 and j= 2. This figure is saved in ./home/folder22 and it has been overwritten with the plots generated in the previous folders as well. How do I avoid this?

[image]

Update: I believe I have to use plt.figure() each time before plotting?

Comment: Can you print out path1 and path2 in every loop and show the output

Comment: Yes. Each time the loop runs, path1 and path2 are as follows: ./home/folder21/a.png ./home/folder21/b.png and so on..

Comment: You can use plt.figure() as you already expected. Easy solution is to just add a counter-variable and set it to 0 before the for-loops and then add one to the value before each plt.scatter() and then have the plt.figure() function call with that counter as parameter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you use `plt.close()` like below:

```
x = [2,4,6]
y = [1,2,3]
for i in x:
    for j in y:
        outputpath = './home/' + 'folder'+ str(i) + str(j)
        if not path.exists(outputpath):
            try:
                os.makedirs(outputpath)
            except OSError:
                print("Creation failed")
            else:
                print("Successfully created")
        a =  np.random.rand(1000)
        b = np.random.rand(20000)
        
        #Plotting a
        plt.scatter((range(0,len(a))),a)
        path1 = outputpath + './' + 'a' + '.png'
        plt.savefig(path1)
        plt.close()


        #Plotting b
        plt.scatter((range(0,len(b))),b)
        path2 = outputpath + './' + 'b' + '.png'
        plt.savefig(path2)
        plt.close()
```